Platform support for Expandable Segments in PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
Apps using torch keep telling me "Expandable Segments not supported on this platform" (namely, EasyDiffusion and EasyTraining GUIs), but I couldn't find anything about the support of this feature. Does it require particular hardware or OS? I could really use the memory saving it should provide.
I'm running Cuda 12.1 on Win10x64 and RTX 2070S 8Gb, torch-2.3.1+cu121, torchvision-0.18.1+cu121. I heard that the last pytorch version that had this feature working was 2.1.2, but trying versions from 2.0.0 to 2.2.1 got me nothing.

Some say that recent edits in cuda allocator header file caused this bug, but a friend of mine with RTX 3060 does not experience these errors (but then it's hard to tell whether these segments are in effect at all). More here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/122057
